# React store dispatch throttling

Tags: reactjs, throttling

So my issue is probably a common one but I haven't seen an explanation of how to do it with hooks/functional components.

I have a controlled input that just has a simple state attached to it. When this input changes it has a handler that first updates said state, then second dispatches the state to the store. What I'm trying to do is update the state immediately (so that the user can type without much lag in the typing) and then throttle the dispatch to only happen once every 300 ms for example because said dispatch is expensive and is what is causing the typing lag.

So here is the way it is:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    setName(value);
    dispatch(actions.editCheckpointPeriod({ id, name }));
};
.
.
.
 <S.Input value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
```

but the https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle-debounce package is not working as I would expect it to when I do something to this effect:

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
        const { value } = event.target;

        setName(value);
        throttle(300, false, () => {
             dispatch(actions.nameAction({ id, value }));
        });
    };
```

In this case the throttle function just never fires.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think keeping form state in redux is a good idea as mentioned in react docs as well. `formik` is a pretty great library to manage your form state.
Anyway, if you keep the state locally then there won’t be any lag, as react handles re-renders and state updates really really quickly.

Comment: I think I would normally agree (single source of truth). Ideally what I would do is keep the form state locally then on submit dispatch the store. In the current UI I have there is no submit button so everything happens asynchronously, which is why in this situation I need to have both.

Comment: You can update global state onBlur event, i think that’ll work for you.

Comment: That's actually a better solution. It's not as sleek but it'll get the job done (cleaner)

Answer (score 1):

That is the incorrect signature.  `debounce` returns a function for you to call.  The function loses the context of being called over and over if you define it within the change handler.  Instead wrap `dispatch` in a debounce or throttle and then call **that** function without the handler.  The way you are doing it now, you just remake the throttled function over and over.

Consider the following example:

```js
import {throttle} from "https://unpkg.com/throttle-debounce@2.1.0/dist/index.esm.js";

function sayWords(word) {
  console.log(word);
}

const throttledSayWords = throttle(1000, sayWords);

setInterval(() => {
  throttledSayWords("Hello");
}, 100);
```

If you ran this example, it would *try* to say hello every 100 milliseconds, but only actually get called every second.

---

So for you, it would look something like this:

```js
import {throttle} from "https://unpkg.com/throttle-debounce@2.1.0/dist/index.esm.js";

const throttledDebounce = throttle(300, false, dispatch);

const handleChange = (event) => {
  const {value} = event.target;

  setName(value);
  throttledDebounce({
    id,
    value
  });
};
```

Comment: when I run this I'm still getting a lag (local state behaving as if it is also being throttled).